# Looking for continuous integration host,or an alternate solution

Tags: .net, continuous-integration

We are a team of remote developers.We want to get CI into our project(dotnet 3.5).Are there any hosts providing CI solutions? If not,how can I go about setting this up?What are my options?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

- If it's open source, you could check into [CodeBetter.com](http://jameskovacs.com/2009/02/24/announcing-teamcitycodebettercom/)
- Google turned up [this](http://mikeci.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Continuous Integration is a great and awesome thing - ironically it is a very simple concept. Simply poll for a change in your source control repository and build if a change is detected.

I do not know of any hosts\services that will do this for you - but it is pretty simple to set up.

One possible solution is to grab [CruiseControl.Net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET), install it to a free (typically clean) machine, and then create a basic ccnet config that

1. polls for changes in repository,
2. pulls changes in repository,
3. invokes MSBuild

there are plenty of resources out there that describe these individual steps and many other additional steps, but this is the basic strategy.

Another two pence: in my experience, the best CI solutions are those that require little maintenance, which typically means maintaining a clean ccnet config. Whenever possible, try to leverage your solution's proj files to enact build tasks. In addition to keeping your ccnet config clean, [there are additional benefits to this approach as well](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/02/fail-early-with-full-builds-from-within.html) :)

Answer (score 1):

[Teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is probably the easiest ane most robust. Free for commercial use.